# Is the site-analytics privilege rolling out site by site? What is the plan?

Tags: support, privileges, site-analytics

I just gained a 25k privilege on Travel, where I have a lot more than 25k rep. So I guess it's a new privilege. Cool! But I haven't gained it on Meta or The Workplace, where I also have over 25k. Why not? Do they not have it yet? When will they?

Comment: Just try the URL manually, I suspect that the bot handing out notifications is still working on it. The site itself seems to be enabled everywhere.

Comment: You got it, but no notifications. I also got only one notification while having 25k on two sites, probably they don't want to clutter the box.

Comment: Notifications run on a schedule and in batches, so you will end up getting notified everywhere. Privilege notifications are also triggered by reputation changes, so it could be that.

Comment: I'm getting notification on reputation changes so far.

Comment: you mean if you already have more than 25k on site X and Y, and gain some rep on X, you get notified about X, but not Y until you gain rep there? That matches my pattern actually - I had rep gain on Travel, got the notification only for Travel, asked here, gained rep here, got notified here.... if I gain any Workplace rep today and then get notified, you'll be right

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The comments are correct: I have it where I expect to have it, though I was (at first) only notified for one (randomly chosen?) site. Since then I have got another notification for Meta. I presume the Workplace notification will show up eventually. (At one point it had been five hours with no sign of it.)

The notification for a site appears immediately after you earn some rep on a site. I guess for existing privileges is there is already a "now that you have more rep, did you gain a priv" code, and when a new priv gets added, rather than spawning a giant check, the system just counts on that code eventually notifying you. As noted above this has nothing to do with whether you have the privilege or not, just when you get notified about it.